# How to ignore classes in test class with ArchUnit

Tags: testing, architecture, classpath, archunit

I wrote my first ArchUnit test:

```
import static com.tngtech.archunit.library.dependencies.SlicesRuleDefinition.*;
// more non-static imports

@RunWith(ArchUnitRunner.class)
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "my.domain.project")
public class PackageStructureTests {

    @ArchTest public static final ArchRule NO_CYCLES = slices().matching("my.domain.project.(**)")
            .namingSlices("package:$1").should().beFreeOfCycles();

}
```

The problem is that it also analyzes classes in tests, which don't follow that simple dependency constraint.

**How do I limit the test to the "production" classes?**

The project gets built with Maven, so the classes are in separate directories.

It is not sufficient to separate classes with names ending in "Tests" or something because there are many classes that aren't tests, but are only present on the test classpath.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It seems that the API is not guiding very well with respect to this, because you're not the first one wondering about this (this was also issue #1 on Github https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/1).

To answer the question though, the Annotation `@AnalyseClasses` has an extra attribute `importOptions`, which takes arbitrary implementations of `ImportOption`. There you can specify which `Location` (basically the URI) to include.

Since excluding tests is rather common, this `ImportOption` is already predefined (for Maven and Gradle < 4.0), so you can write

```
@AnalyzeClasses(..., importOptions = ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class)
public class MyTest{ ... }
```

I don't think, there is a generic solution for all setups (thus the freedom to just write your own `ImportOption` to decide which locations to include). However, for standard Maven and Gradle setups, it should be working.

Comment: `DontIncludeTests` is deprecated (checked in ArchUnit 0.10.2). Use `DoNotIncludeTests` (different spelling).

Answer (score 13):

In case you are not using [archunit-junit](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_using_junit_4) (ArchUnit's JUnit4-support as time of writing), but using "native" ArchUnit, use (for example)

```
com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses classes 
  = new com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter()
    .withImportOption(
      new com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests())
    .importPackages("my.random.package");
```

Comment: ImportOption.DontIncludeTests() is deprecated use instead: `ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests()`

Comment: It is available via Enum: ImportOption.Predefined.DO_NOT_INCLUDE_TESTS